# Delphi FireMonkey Button StyleLookup Icon color

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

10.1.2 can use IconTintColor properties to set the styleLookup icon color. How about 10.2?

Now I'm using the fillrgbeffect control to change the color, but when you click on the button, the stylelookup icon has a color around the icon and icon.This is not what I want

The original properties can only be used on android.

---

Here is the method I use now.

1. Create a new filemonkey application;
2. Add a button control to the form and set the stylelookup for any property value;
3. Add a TFillRGBEffect control, then attach the TFillRGBEffect control to the button, and set the color property of the TFillRGBEffect to any color, so that the stylelookup icon of the button changes color.

But when I run the program, and you click on button, there's also a color value outside of the icon, and I just want to change the color of the stylelookup icon, which is the same thing when I click on it.

In version 10.1.2, you can set the icontintcolor property of button directly, but 10.2 doesn't know how to do it.

Comment: You don't need to be sorry for your english, but you should be sorry for providing so little detail. You do understand that we can't see your screen, don't you? We need more detail, how can we reproduce the problem? What steps should we take to see it? Maybe you can use the Windows Snipping Tool or similar to take an image of the button? If there are code involved, you must provide the relevant parts of it.

Comment: @lovemit SO isn't a discussion forum. It's a **Question** and Answer site. You don't reply to anyone, you update your question so it's understandable and *relevant* to others. Formatting matters too. You can't expect anyone to solve the problem if they can't even understand what you are asking

Comment: @lovemit in short, you *can* and *should* edit your own question to improve it